# Does CVE-2012-0883 apply to Ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, security

Does the Apache vulnerability [CVE-2012-0883](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-0883) affect Ubuntu? Have tried searching for it at [ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com/search/google-appliance/CVE-2012-0883) but with no hits.

I note that Ubuntu releases an Ubuntu Security Notice (USN) when it issues an update for the vulnerability e.g. [USN-1627-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-1627-1/) for CVE-2012-2687 and CVE-2012-4929. However I cannot find any corresponding USN for CVE-2012-0883 although I did find this:

http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-0883.html

And if Ubuntu is not affected by the vulnerability, what version of Apache contains the fix?

Comment: JBusch - you appear to have multiple accounts - please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your other accounts are merged.  Once done, you'll be able to edit your question and accept any answers that your believe helped you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It's clearly written in the [page you have linked](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-0883.html):

```
Upstream:                               released (2.4.2)
Ubuntu 8.04 LTS (Hardy Heron):          not-affected
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx):          not-affected
Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal):           not-affected
Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot):          not-affected
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin):    not-affected
```

Also, in the same page, there's written:

> jdstrand> Debian/Ubuntu packages contain 038_no_LD_LIBRARY_PATH (see
>   http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=276670 for more information)

And if you look at the changelog included in the bug you can see:

```
apache2 (2.0.52-2) unstable; urgency=high
[...]
  * Move envvars to /etc/apache2/ and add patch 038_no_LD_LIBRARY_PATH to
    remove the extraneous LD_LIBRARY_PATH from envvars (closes: #276670)
```

This means that the bug has been fixed in Debian since version **2.0.52**.

Last but not least, if you look at your `/etc/apache2/envvars` or `/usr/share/apache2/build/envvars-std`, you'll see that they don't contain any malicious `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.